# Is there a syntax for accessing table names containing slashes?

Tags: sql-server-2005, linked-server

I have a linked server registered in my SQL Server 2005 which accesses our SAP database (test system). It uses an ODBC driver provided by SAP, and is connected using the Microsoft OLEDB For ODBC driver. The remote database is a MaxDB 7.7.

I'm currently exploring the possibilities of directly accessing data within our SAP system, but have run into problems regarding certain tables.

The following works without problems:

```
SELECT Field FROM LinkedServer..Schema.Table WHERE MANDT = '110'
```

or, respectively

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(LinkedServer, 'SELECT Field FROM Table WHERE MANDT = ''110''')
```

Now, there's some nasty table names within SAP that can contain slashes. I think it's meant to be a "namespace" type of thing contained within the actual table name. On the ABAP side of things, I can easily do

```
SELECT * FROM /MYWHATEVER/MYTABLE
```

provided the table exists. But I can't get the table names containing `/` working via linked server.

Trying

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(LinkedServer, 'SELECT * FROM /MYWHATEVER/MYTABLE')
```

gives me "Error 7321 while preparing query...". Using

```
SELECT * FROM LinkedServer..Schema.[/MYWHATEVER/MYTABLE]
```

yields "Error 7306 OLEDB-Provider "MSDASQL" can't open table "Schema./MYWHATEVER/MYTABLE" for linked server LinkedServer, it contains errors or doesn't exist".

Is there any way I can access tables containing `/` on a MaxDB via LinkedServer?

<sup><sub>[The error messages may not be literally the same as on an english system, since I had to translate them from german]</sub></sup>

Comment: Does it work if you quote the table name (using single-quotes as per the ANSI standard)?

Comment: @Gonsalu Thanks for the hint, masking using double quotes `"` works for one of the two cases, see my comment on gbn's answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try escaping stuff and see what happens

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(LinkedServer, 'SELECT * FROM //MYWHATEVER//MYTABLE')
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(LinkedServer, 'SELECT * FROM \/MYWHATEVER\/MYTABLE')
...
```

I assume that the local ODBC layer is bollixing you. The bit inside OPENQUERY should be a literal to SQL Server so it is external to SQL Server. So it could be be the ODBC layer: can you profile (or log) what happens on the MaxDB to see what gets through?

Another option would be use a view or proc in the MaxDB to give "proper" names

Comment: Thanks, after experimenting for a while, it seems that using `"` to mask the table names works when using the OPENQUERY syntax like this: `SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(LinkedServer, 'SELECT * FROM "//MYWHATEVER//MYTABLE"')`. No luck using that on the three dot syntax though, `SELECT * FROM LinkedServer..Schema.["/MYWHATEVER/MYTABLE"]` still does not work. No luck with profiling/logging yet, I'd need someone from the SAP team to look at that.